# I am unable to append multiple times using the createdocumentfragment JS call

Tags: javascript

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".test");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  a1 = document.createElement('h5');
  a1.className = "bluecolor";
  a1.innerHTML = 'Blue updated';
  console.log(a1); //console log output is <h5 class="first">Blue updated.</h5>

  document.getElementById('position').innerText = null; //clear the position 
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); //create fragment
  fragment.append(a1); //append a1 element to the fragment,works 1st time only
  fragment.append(a1); //append a1 element to the fragment
  fragment.append(a1); //append a1 element to the fragment
  fragment.append(a1); //append a1 element to the fragment   
  fragment.append(a1); //append a1 element to the fragment  
  document.getElementById('position').append(fragment); //append the fragment to the DOM tree 

});
```

```css
.first,
.test {
  color: bluecolor;
}
```

```html
<h5 id="position">Text to be replaced</h5>
<button class="test">blue</button>
```

Upon clicking the 'blue' button, I wanna display the text 'Blue color updated' 5 times at once  using the [createdocumentfragmentAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) but the text 'Blue color updated' updates 1 time only even though I am trying to use the below process mentioned in the createdocumentfragment docs:

> **The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children.
> **
> so where am I am going conceptually wrong , please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way the DOM works. If you append an existing element that is already in the DOM (or in this case a DOM fragment) in another place, the element is moved, not copied.

You would need to create new elements if you wish to insert them in a different place.

Answer (score 2):

Other are already explain issue.\

Use `cloneNode` property to clone your existing element.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".test");
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            a1 = document.createElement('h5');
            a1.className = "bluecolor";
            a1.innerHTML = 'Blue updated';
            console.log(a1); //console log output is <h5 class="first">Blue updated.</h5>

            document.getElementById('position').innerText = null; //clear the position 
            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); //create fragment
            fragment.append(a1.cloneNode(true)); //append a1 element to the fragment,works 1st time only
            fragment.append(a1.cloneNode(true)); //append a1 element to the fragment
            fragment.append(a1.cloneNode(true)); //append a1 element to the fragment
            fragment.append(a1.cloneNode(true)); //append a1 element to the fragment   
            fragment.append(a1.cloneNode(true)); //append a1 element to the fragment  
            document.getElementById('position').append(fragment); //append the fragment to the DOM tree 

        });
```

```html
<h5 id="position">Text to be replaced</h5>
    <button class="test">blue</button>
```